# Chaining puppet providers

Tags: puppet, apache-nifi

I'm using [Apache Nifi](https://nifi.apache.org/) and I'm writing a [tool](https://github.com/icalvete/nifi_sdk_ruby) to automate it based on [Nifi API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html). This tool is a ruby gem so I want use it as a puppet type / provider inside my [Nifi manifest](https://github.com/icalvete/puppet-nifi).

Type (*lib/puppet/type/nifi_pg.rb*) looks like this:

```rb
Puppet::Type.newtype(:nifi_pg) do
  @doc = "Manage Nifi process groups"

  ensurable

  newparam(:name) do

    isnamevar

    desc "Process group Name"

    validate do |value|
    end
  end

  newparam(:id) do
    desc "Process group ID"

    validate do |value|
    end
  end
end
```

Provider (*lib/puppet/provider/nifi_pg/ruby.rb*) looks like this:

```rb
require 'nifi_sdk_ruby'

Puppet::Type.type(:nifi_pg).provide(:ruby) do

    def create
        nifi_client = Nifi.new()
        nifi_client.set_debug(true)
        nifi_client.create_process_group(:name => resource[:name])
    end

    def destroy
        nifi_client = Nifi.new()
        nifi_client.set_debug(true)
        nifi_client.delete_process_group(resource[:id])
    end

    def exists?
        false
    end
end
```

Use it is easy:

```rb
nifi_pg {"test":
  ensure => present
}
```

The problem is I need some information about the created resource (Like new process group ID) to use it to, for example, upload a template to this new process group. Puppet resources don't return anything.

Any idea to workaround?

I think the answer is not.

This [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263746/puppet-how-to-use-the-exec-return-value-as-a-trigger) explain it perfectly.

Comment: Off the top of my head, this is not possible because facts and functions execute at compilation time, and you need one or both to solve this problem. However, could you edit your question for this theoretical template as to what the resource and template look like? There may be a workaround for that case.

Comment: Alternatively, is this something that needs to execute on the node? If not, there is a path forward there too.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way to accomplish this, but Puppet allows you to [`exec` arbitrary commands](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/exec.html), and you can combine this with `curl` to hit the [NiFi REST API](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) and retrieve any process group ID necessary. Extract the PG ID to a Ruby variable and simply reference it in your next command.

Comment: This is not what he is asking. He wants to do it in one catalog application, which is impossible with your suggestion.

Comment: Can the `curl` script be defined as an ["external fact"](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/2.1/custom_facts.html#external-facts) which is referenced from the Ruby code?

Comment: No, because those are resolved during catalog compilation before application.